# R.O.B can't move up or down

Tags: nes, repair

I got this R.O.B (Robotic Operating Buddy for the NES), first time I turned him on his arms wouldn't close, so I took him apart and cleaned him. I put the gears back into place. After turning him on again and testing him he won't move up or down. His arms open and close now, but they are a little loose and don't line up straight (I don't have all the screws in the case so that's probably the problem) the gears look like they are all in the right place. Any ideas? (Also, why can't I upload a picture? It says "error logged" after it loads)

Comment: Probably remote troubleshooting of the motion of a robot is best done with a Youtube video of what you did, what it looks like inside, and what it is or isn't doing. Include the link to the video in your question. I've never seen inside a ROB so can't suggest anything.

Comment: Try uploading a picture now. It might work.

Comment: Wizz, still no good. Do I have to have so much reputation before before I can post pics?

Comment: Do you hear the "climbing motor" make any noise when it attempts to go up/down? Does it budge at all?

Comment: Bjb, it does make a sound, it worked before I took it apart to fix the arms. I have rob taken apart right now. I tried adding a pic of his body but I can't upload pictures.

Comment: Perhaps put them in a google album or imgurl account and share the link.

Comment: Sorry for such a late update. One of the ground wires on a motor got pinched. I. Re soldered it, his arms move fine now. But I still cant get him to move up, he can move down though.  I gluded the gear that moves him up and down with super glue. I know its not loose now. Could the motor be bad? He makes a alwful sound when he trys to move up.

Comment: The motor could be old enough where it could be in dead-lock, where there is being power supplied to the motor, but it's so old that it can't move or make an initial spin.

Comment: I wished I had a R.O.B..  Probably be better company than most of the people I have to deal with.